# Move canvas image object after rotating

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

After rotating an image in canvas is cropped. How can I adjust the image to canvas size?

```
$("#rotate").click(function(){
var curAngle = canvas.item(0).getAngle();
if(curAngle == 360)
    curAngle = 0
if(curAngle == 0 || curAngle == 180){
    canvas.setHeight(200);
    canvas.setWidth(400);
}
if(curAngle == 90 || curAngle == 270){
    canvas.setHeight(400);
    canvas.setWidth(200);   
}

canvas.item(0).setAngle(curAngle+90);

canvas.renderAll();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3efe2x9j/21/

Answer (score 0):

A bit of trig is required here. You should work in radians not degrees. 360 == Math.PI*2 and 180 == Math.PI.

We need to calculate the total height and width of the rotated box;

```
// ang is the rotation in radians
// width and height are the box... you know.

// get the height of the width when rotated
var topHeight  = Math.abs( Math.sin( ang ) ) * width; // we only want positive number
var leftHeight = Math.abs( Math.cos( ang ) ) * height; 
var topWidth   = Math.abs( Math.cos( ang ) ) * width;
var leftWidth  = Math.abs( Math.sin( ang ) ) * height;

// now we can get the total width and height of the rotated box
var totalWidth  = topWidth + leftWidth;
var totalHeight = topHeight + leftHeight;
```

Hope this helps.